# Will double strike still do anything if I Cloudshift my blocker?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My friend attacks with a creature with double strike (e.g. [Boros Swiftblade](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Boros%20Swiftblade)). I block with a creature, then I [Cloudshift](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cloudshift) it. Do I or my creature take any damage from the double strike?

Answer (score 3):

If you cast Cloudshift during the Declare Blockers Step, specifically rule 509.5, than your creature will not suffer combat damage (506.4), but the Creature with Double Strike is still considered Blocked for the Combat Damage Step. It will assign no damage for either the first strike or normal combat damage portions.

> **510.1c** A blocked creature assigns its combat damage to the creatures blocking it. If no creatures are currently blocking it (if, for example, they were destroyed or removed from combat), it assigns no combat damage.

Comment: The crucial rule that should be mentioned is that a creature that leaves the battlefield for any length of time (e.g. through Cloudshift) is also removed from combat.

Comment: The two relevant rules are probably "400.7. An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence." and "506.4. A permanent is removed from combat if it leaves the battlefield, ..."

Comment: And it will be the full damage, since there is no longer a blocker to 'soak' up some of the damage with its toughness.

Comment: Trample is beyond the scope of the question.